# flutter doctor Unable to determine Android Studio version

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, android-studio

[image]

I installed Flutter on Linux Mint. Also, I installed Android Studio,
but when I run `flutter doctor -v` in the **CLI**, it gives me the error:

```
type here[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
```

```
flutter --version
```

```
Flutter 3.13.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ff5b5b5fa6 (7 weeks ago) • 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
Engine • revision b20183e040
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0


Dart SDK version: 3.1.0 (stable) (Tue Aug 15 21:33:36 2023 +0000) on "linux_x64"
```

Comment: Related issue from github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135662

Comment: what if I have installed the cannery and stable both studio and run parallel, showing the same error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem.

As you can see `flutter doctor -v` is finding two copies of android studio.

The first one it has a version number so all is good. The second one is in the `opt/` directory which is actually just containg a link to android studio. Your just going to want to delete this link.

You can do this by `cd ../../opt` and then your in the opt directory.

Now run `sudo rm -r android-studio` to remove the link

Then `cd ../home/yourusername` to navigate back

Then `flutter doctor -v` and you should have no issues

Comment: Can you answer the question for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu when Android Studio installed with snap it installed into `/snap/android-studio/current`. In Terminal enter `flutter config --android-studio-dir /snap/android-studio/current` and run `flutter doctor -v`